# Volatile атомарность

Tags: java

Правильно ли я понимаю что ключевое слово обеспечивает атомарность только в однопоточной среде, а в многопоточной нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

volatile не обеспечивает атомарность. Его назначение — указать, что переменная может измениться в другом потоке. Следовательно, когда происходит работа с ней, её значение необходимо пересчитывать, а не использовать кэшированную или регистровую копию.

Comment: Не совсем правильно, в пределах волатильной переменной атомарность обеспечивается, переменная не может быть повреждена при неполном изменении.

Comment: `volatile` [обеспечивает](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) атомарность. И ни про какие кэши в спеке ни слова, вы путаете с C++. В Java дается [консистентность чтения/записи](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).